# Подобрать алгоритм для задачи на массивы

Tags: c++, массивы, олимпиада

Задача следующая: Вводятся 2 массива, нужно найти 2 таких числа из каждого массива, чтобы разность между ними была минимальна.

### Пример 1:

**Ввод:**

```
3 4

1 2 3
```

**Вывод:**

```
3 3
```

### Пример 2:

**Ввод:**

```
4 5

1 2 3
```

**Вывод:**

```
4 3
```

Перебором задача решается очень долго, особенно если массивы большие. Подскажите, пожалуйста, может существует алгоритм, позволяющий решить задачу без перебора? Я слышал про бинарный поиск, применим ли он в этой ситуации? Я прошу только алгоритм, помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Валишь массивы в одну кучу, но оставляешь пометку, откуда элемент. Сортируешь (можно ещё выкинуть средние, если три или более подряд из одного массива). Ищешь пару, чтобы и разность минимальна, и из разных массивов.

Comment: Или сортируешь по отдельности, и обрабатываешь параллельно, с двумя курсорами.

Comment: Действительно, можно и бинарным поиском, сортируем один из масивов, потом перебираем каждый елемент другого и ищем ближайшее число к текущему в отсортированом масиве и на каждом шаге обновляем минимальное значение) тоесть сложность будет nlog(m) + mlog(m) = (n + m)log(m) что есть явно меньше n*m

Comment: IMHO, @Akina оптимальное решение подсказал. Если массивы уже отсортированы, то сложность будет `O(n+m)`, а если нет, то `n*log(n) + m*log(m) + n + m`.